# How to check List contains the particular element null or not in Struts 2 using <s:if> Tags?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have an action in Struts 2, I want to test whether email ID is empty or `null` using `<s:if>` test condition in JSP.

```
class EmailAction extends ActionSupport  {
      private ArrayList<Email> emailList;
      //setter and getters
}

class Email   {
     private String username;
     Private String password;
     private String emailId;
     //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide getter for `emailId`

```
<s:if test="emailId == null || emailId == ''">
```